# Where can I find the errors list of "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" written by Phillip Griffths and Joseph Harris?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have bought the book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" written by Phillip Griffths and Joseph Harris? Where can I find the errors list of the book?

Comment: Why not to try using this link http://www.math.miami.edu/highlights/events/lecture-series-by-phillip-griffiths-2019/ and ask them ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I am not sure I understand the relevance of the link you posted.

Comment: Look at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13000/errata-to-principles-of-algebraic-geometry-by-griffiths-and-harris