# Where can I find the errors list/errata of Introduction to algebraic curves by Phillip A. Griffiths?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, self-learning, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I couldn't find on overflow unlike with this question: [Where can I find the errors list of "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" written by Phillip Griffths and Joseph Harris?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302349/where-can-i-find-the-errors-list-of-principles-of-algebraic-geometry-written-b)

Comment: Probably by trying to Google it, or use Google Scholar.  I say that because I searched Google myself and found the errat to the text you list in your link.  If it's out there somewhere, you'll find errata to your current query on Google, or Google Scholar.  If that search fails to turn it up, then you'll know it's not currently available.

Comment: @amWhy wait you mean you found an errata to  “Principles of Algebraic Geometry” written by Phillip Griffths and Joseph Harris that wasn't the overflow link?

Comment: Griffiths and Harris is the standard text in the subject area, so MO finds it worth wide to keep an errata. Don't expect to find many errata there. You have to search on google.